# how to try different path planning algoritms in Rriz

Tags: ros, navigation, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hİ

How is it possible to try different global path planning algorithms in Rviz ?

http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280411/how-to-try-different-path-planning-algoritms-in-rriz/) by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2018-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you should setup the move_base first .maybe you can get some help from this tutorial[navigation_stage](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation_stage).But stage simulator is for 2D navigation,so if you want to simulation in 3D ,just choose other.

in this tutorial,you can change the type of globalplanner in move_base.xml in navigation_stage/move_base_config/ as you like and re-launch the package .good luck!

---

Originally posted by [pengjiawei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31790/pengjiawei/) with karma: 138 on 2018-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on 2018-01-24**:
thank you!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-05-11**:
@Developer if this answered your question then please click the checkmark to mark the answer as correct.